# How can I get the value from the selected radio button in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with my code..
I want to get the value from radio button when selected and calculate the value of the selected radio button.
And showing the result in input text.

[image]

Comment: the same you get the value from any other input

Comment: Post your code that has issue.

Comment: Data from the table is the result of a query

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var szradio = '<input type="radio" name="gender" value="1"> Male<br>  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="2"> Female<br>  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="3"> Other'

        $('#div_content').append(szradio)

        $('body').on('change','input[name="gender"]',function () {

            $('#txtInput').val($(this).val())
        });


 });  
</script>
</head>
<body>


    <input type="text" id="txtInput"/>
    <br />

  <div id="div_content">


  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Shriya R. It really helping.

Comment: what if the radio button name is the result of array in PHP?
example:
gender$i.
And calculate all the selected radio value?

Comment: I have run this code and working. But when the alert show the last selected radio button still checked and calculate total. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: do u want to get the all the selected radio val as the sum??